# Xenserver storage overbooking

Tags: xen

I do not find any information about this topic. Can I overbook my storage of virtual disks on XenServer 6.2? E.g I have a 2TB storage and 2 VM's with 2TB virtual disks each.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xenserver 6.2 with around 12 VMS and 4 TB of storage.

One of the things I've notice is that even if the size of one vdi (virtual disk) is fixed, the amount really used on disk is variable depending on how full the disks are.

For example, if you create the VMs with 2 TB each this is a possible scenario:

- VM1 after install and some moderated use is using 1 TB out of 2 TB. The vhd file would be around 1 TB of use on the storage drive.
- VM2 after install is using 200 GB out of 2 TB. It also uses on disk around that size on the storage.

The problems you might encounter depends on the total amount of space you have on your SR. 
When the vdis increase in size, they don't release the space after that. 
Lets say you delete 500 GB from VM1 it will still use 1 TB on the storage, and if you increase the size of VM2 over your storage limit, problems will appear. Probably the SO will stop working is there's no more space to allocate.

I hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use NFS, or re-create your LUN with ext3 filesystem.
This will help you to over assign the storage, but you have to make sure actual disk usage dont go beyond 2TB.